# Are VHD's (Virtual Hard Drives) safe?

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-drive

So, All I'm asking is if Virtual Hard Drives are safe. Because I needed more space and well.. My external hard-drive only has around 50GB of space (30GB taken by the system), so I'm thinking of making a VHD to store my games in. Will my games get corrupted or something? I'm not sure if I should make a VHD.

Comment: You do understand a 30 GB virtual HDD (VHDD) requires 30 GB of free space?  What you plan on doing does not make sense.  If your external HDD does not have enough space, then you still need a larger external HDD, in order to store the virtual HDD file.

Comment: OK, another thing. How do I delete VHD's once i make one

Comment: You select the file and delete it.

Comment: You should reboot your system then attempt to delete the file.  I am going to assume you have mistakenly mounted the .vhd file from within Windows.

Comment: Do you run the Disk Cleanup manager? __cleanmgr.exe__ I would not be surprised if you could gain several gigabyes from running it and allowing it to run the Windows Update Cleanup. You must run it as administrator, (create a short on the desktop and then you can right-click it to run).

Answer (score 2):

VHD is not a magical [hammerspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammerspace)-type free disk space. It's a isolated slice of disk that can be used as if it's a completely separate disk. To make a 30 GB VHD you have to sacrifice 30 GB of your disk space first. You can't just conjure free disk space out of thin air.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Hard drives add another complication and offer no advantage for your situation. If you need more space, you need to acquire another, preferably larger, HDD or SSD.

Once added to your PC, you could either

a) clone your existing drive and its apps onto the new drive, then make it the boot drive, or

b) move everything which isn't the OS or an app to the new drive. Move your media files; movies, music, documents. Move your virtual memory drive to the new drive. Move the location of TMP and TEMP files. Move all the backup images. Sounds like work, but it's easier than cloning then reconfiguring your PC to boot from the new drive, and will result in a performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same idea for storing PC Games in a VHD container , not in ISO. its okay idea, go for it. There is not risk here, just check Read Only on VHD or VHDX , just in case your antivirus deletes some crack, keygen etc. , when you mount them.

Good Luck,